# Is optical-illusion responsible for Loch Ness monster?

Tags: optics, solitons

When you look out at the white-caps on a wind-swept lake, you can see a dark, undulating pattern under the crests of the white-caps.

*Could this shadow-like area explain the sightings?* Revised, see below.

**Edit** First of all, it must be a rogue wave, [image: rogue wave], so it stands out from the rest of the waves (if any). This could be the hump of some monster just breaking the surface!

[Question on Cognitive Science.SE about eyewitness perceptions.](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5154/eyewitness-perceptions-of-the-loch-ness-monster)

**Edit** You are walking along a country lane, when a sudden motion on the water catches your eye. Followed by the sound of a crashing wave. Within seconds, only ripples remain on the surface. You remember the image as shown above. It could be a white-cap on a wave, but everyone who has been to the beach knows that waves come in one-after-another, and there are no other waves, so it can't be a wave. You notice the darker area under the white-cap and realize the only possible explanation is: you have just seen a large animal dive under the surface. Like a sounding whale. (Or monster?).

Loch Ness is located near a major fault line that has seismic activity. Physicists can explain that a wave created by seismic activity is a rogue wave or tsunami. They can also explain why the wave does not reach shore and, why the area under the white-cap is always darker.

**So, could a collaboration between physics and psychology show this illusion is a possible explanation for Nessi?**

Comment: Would http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: Heresy!  The Loch Ness Monster (cousin of the Lake Champlain Monster) **creates** those illusions to fool the nonbelievers!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about physics

Comment: I think it's an interesting question but could use more details.

Comment: It is an interesting question indeed, but it needs both psychology and physics so that the former can answer how human *perceptions* respond to proposed physical mechanisms. The physics side of things would be to find out what phenomena (I don't know, soliton water waves, maybe) can be mooted to explain effects and then to analyse how likely and often they would arise at Loch Ness. Then, psychology would need to analyse the likely perceptual response to each.

Comment: BTW Fred is that photo real? Where from? I can imagine such a thing happenning if there is a steep shelf dropoff near the shore.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, I googled "rogue wave images" and found that. https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj-_QnBy8hkicu1Mvz4l4-np1Xfl6dkqs8cQRI5J8zLDxcu3tbzA

Comment: Seeing the picture I vote to reopen. After all perception is what we gather data to  study physics with. Seems to me one could fit a monster under that rogue wave.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, I agree that the steep shelf scenario is the most likely.  One could build a model of Loch Ness, fill it with water, and trigger miniture tsunamis to determine if that kind of behavior can happen.

Comment: One could also just drain the lake and look for a big plesiosauric animal on the bottom. Then we'd have conclusive proof one way or the other. :D